# Translation of "Chesed" in the Septuagint, LXX

Tags: greek, septuagint

My question is about the Greek word that was used to translate "chesed" Psalm 136:1 in the Septuagint. Is the same Greek word always used to translate "chesed" in the Septuagint?

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent question and welcome to BHSX.  Please do not forget to take the tour below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hebrew and Greek text followed by the LEH lexicon entry for τὸ ἔλεος. According to T. Muraoka's Index there are more than a dozen different greek words used to translate "chesed" חסד.

psa 136:1 הוֹדוּ לַיהוָה כִּי־טוֹב כִּי לְעוֹלָם חַסְדּֽוֹ

Psa. 135:1 ¶    Αλληλουια.
    Ἐξομολογεῖσθε τῷ κυρίῳ, ὅτι χρηστός,
    ὅτι εἰς τὸν αἰῶνα τὸ ἔλεος αὐτοῦ·

חַסְדּֽוֹ   "chesed" + pronominal suffix is translated by τὸ ἔλεος αὐτοῦ where αὐτοῦ reflects the pronominal suffix.

> ἔλεος Gn 19:19; 24:12,14,44,49
>       pity, mercy, compassion  Gn 19:19; ἔλεος ποιέω ἔν τινι to deal mercifully with  Gn 40:14; [ἐπί τινα] TobS 7:12; [μετά τινος] Gn 24:12; [τινι] Gn 24:14; 
>       *Ps 83(84):12 ἔλεον corr.? ἥλιου sun  for MT שׁמשׁ (sun shaped) shield
>       Cf. GRIBOMONT 1959, 83-85; LE BOULLUEC 1989, 338